# Symfony Call to a member function format() on null while sending a message

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am trying to send a message after persisting. When I use regular way it works fine

**addReservatieAction:**

```
    public function addReservatieAction(Request $request, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{  //the rest of the code is also here
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
            ->setFrom('example@live.nl')
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setBody("$success,<br>Email:$email,<br>Name:$name,<br>
                        StartDate:$start_date,<br>EndDate:$end_date", 'text/html');

        $mailer->send($message);

    }
```

But I want make another function for mail like this:

**addReservatieAction:**

```
     public function addReservatieAction(Request $request, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {

        $reservatie = new reservatie();

        $form = $this->createForm(reservatieType::class, $reservatie);
       $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $message=$this->sendEmail();
            //add flashbag is room is booked
            $mailer->send($message);

            $url = $this->generateUrl('index_reservatie');

            return $this->redirect($url);
        }

  public function sendEmail (){

        $reservatie = new reservatie();

        $start_date = $reservatie->getDateIn();
        $start_date = $start_date->format('d-m-y');

        $end_date = $reservatie->getDateOut();
        $end_date = $end_date->format('d-m-y');

        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
            ->setFrom('example@live.nl')
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setBody(" StartDate:$start_date,<br>EndDate:$end_date", 'text/html');

        return $message;

    }
```

But the problem is it keeps giving me this error:

> Call to a member function format() on null

I am using on date and it is not null.

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone is going to read this wall of code. Try to reduce your question to more readable form.

Comment: Table availabilities and table price are just to explain they are not code. the ony code I really need to get worked is in controller. if I get the tables out then my question will be unclear.

Comment: pls dump(end_date) a post results

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to dump in this case, because I am not rendering result in template. When I use email function in addReservatieAction without separating in another function it works fine. The end_date is an object en is being filled by a form

Comment: When I dump start_date In my form it gives `+vars: array:25 [▼
    "value" => "2017-09-27T00:00:00+02:00"
    "attr" => array:2 [▶]
    "form" => FormView {#642}
    "id" => "app_bundlereservatie_type_dateIn"`